# passenger setup for rbenv in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, rbenv

I have some questions.

1. Is it possible (or appropriate) to use `rbenv` in production?
2. Should I install `rbenv` as root, or normal user?
3. How passenger can know which ruby version it should use for a application? Can passenger recognize `.ruby-version` file?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use `rbenv` in production, cause it have sense only if you required to have several ruby versions in the same time.

I would recommend to use system ruby from you OS repository.

**EDIT:** According your questions

1. It is quite possible to use `rbenv` in production (as well as `rvm`). But I would recommend to use ruby from your OS repositories.
2. You may install either as user or root.
3. You should use `.ruby-version` to point to the right version.

Comment: Without version manager, how can I upgrade ruby version safely? Say I run rails with ruby 2.1.1, but want to upgrade to 2.2.0. If I use system ruby, it seems dangerous change system ruby on which rails application is running on.

Comment: Most of the systems allow you to install several version in the same time and switch it using particular command. (for Debian/Ubuntu it'll be `update-alternatives`)

Comment: Say I have installed ruby 2.2.0 on ~/.rbenv/versions, and I have rails application on ~/my_app, and ~/my_app/.ruby-version is set to 2.2.0. How passenger can know where to find ruby? I assume passenger is not related with any ruby manager. Am I wrong?

Comment: I personally never used `passenger` with `rbenv` only with system ruby. But here is the article how to do so: https://intercityup.com/blog/deploying-app-env-variables-with-rbenv-passenger-and-capistrano.html